# How did the high priest dress outside the Temple?

Tags: clothing, kohen-gadol

We know in detail the clothes of the kohen gadol, which he wore specifically for service in the Temple, which he could not wear outside of it.

Did the kohen gadol have specific clothes that he wore outside the Temple? The kings of Israel, for example, wore crowns. Did the kohen gadol wear anything to emphasize his status?

Comment: "The kings of Israel, for example, wore crowns." How do you know this?

Comment: White shirt, black suit and trilby hat of course. (~ptij)

Comment: Mishna Yoma 7:5 indicates that he might own a white robe

Answer (score 4):

It is forbidden for the Kohen Gadol to wear the *bigdei kehunah* outside of the Beis Hamikdash (see, for example, [Rambam Klei Hamikdash 8:10](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=85905&rid=7916)).

However, according to [Rabbeinu Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam) ([Yuma 69a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%A1%D7%98_%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA), [Kiddushin 66a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%95_%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA)), the Kohen Gadol would wear the *[tzitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_golden_head_plate)* even outside. According to one opinion in the *tannaim*, *ritzui tzitz* requires the Kohen Gadol to be wearing the *tzitz*, Tosfos posits that accordingly he would wear the *tzitz* even outside the Beis Hamikdash.

Even according to the conflicting opinions that *ritzui tzitz* is effective without the Kohen Gadol wearing it - and therefore it wouldn't be necessary for the Kohen Gadol to wear outside - it is still permitted, as derived from the verse 'והיה על מצחו תמיד' (Shemos 28:38).

> מיהו למאן דאמר (לעיל ז:) דווקא עודהו על מצחו מרצה יכול להניחו כל שעה
> ואור"ת דלכולי עלמא יכול להניחו כל שעה מדכתיב ביה והיה על מצחו תמיד

Tosfos (Yuma ad loc) cites an alternative opinion that it is forbidden to wear even the *tzitz* outside of the Beis Hamikdash.